# @interface multiple classes

Tags: ios, cocoa

My code looks like this:

```
#import "viewControllerWithTable.h"

@interface SettingsViewController : ViewControllerWithTable{
}
@end
```

however I'm also need to have the interface accessible with 
 SettingsViewController : InputCommandViewController

I need multiple ways of hitting it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "accessible"? Are you saying that you want multiple inheritance?

Comment: That is correct, I want multiple inheritances.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't support multiple inheritance. If you describe what you're trying to accomplish, someone might be able to suggest a different way (like using protocols) to get what you want.

Comment: basically in the SettingsViewController.h file, I need the @interace to have 2 inheritances.  first being ViewControllerWithTable and the other is InputCommandViewController.  The SettingsViewController can be governed by either ViewControllerWithTable or InputCommandViewController.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @ACE: As already stated, Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance. I will echo Ian Henry's question and clarify that I think we are both asking for you to describe the general idea or problem you’re trying to solve, **not how you think you would like to implement it** (since, quite obviously, what you have described so far is impossible). Namely, what **specifically** do each of these 3 classes do, and why do you think you need multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

you would #import the SettingsViewController.h in your InputCommandViewController.h file probably...
you can also use @class directive if you need to represent the class in a header, but don't need the specifics, ie an iVar..

if you want multiple inheritance (as in multiple parents) you can't do that directly you will need to accomplish that in one of three ways:

1) a protocol that defines the interface

2) encapsulate an instance of one of the objects that you need to inherit from, then send the appropriate messages

3) assign an instance of one of the parents as your delegate and send appropriate messages to it.